# Dynamically loading a html template into an existing dynamically loaded div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have to dynamically load a html template into index.html. Now I want to load another html template into the previously loaded template code.

In other words:
index loaded with dashboard template, dashboard has
`<div id='sidebar'>` which will be loaded with sidebar template

```
$("body").load("dashboard.html");
$(document).on('click', '#sidebar', function(){
    $("#sidebar).load("sidebar.html");
});
```

The above code requires a manual click to load the sidebar into the page. I want it to be loaded automatically when the page loads (Both the dashboard and sidebar)

I am using jQuery. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

To do this, put the second `load()` call in the callback of the first, so that it's executed after the `dashboard.html` content has been added to the DOM.

```
$("body").load("dashboard.html", function() {
  $("#sidebar").load("sidebar.html");
});
```